# Where to ask questions about puzzles?

Tags: discussion

Where can I ask questions about puzzles? The FAQ has no link :\

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#what-are-some-examples-of-boardgames-that-are-on-topic-here

> We're not the right place to ask questions about:
>
> - Computer games, try gaming.stackexchange.com
> - Role Playing games, try rpg.stackexchange.com
> - Puzzles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After countless months of building and at least one re-proposal, the [Puzzling Stack Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) is now live and ready for questions:

> Puzzling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those who study the creation and solving of puzzles.

Answer (score 7):

That's because there isn't a StackExchange site for puzzles yet. If you're interested though, there is one in the commitment phase at Area 51. Go and add your name there, and the site is one step closer to launching!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16410/puzzling